# Less Useable Partiton on Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, gparted, filemanager

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I have 256 nvme ssd as main storage (OS is in it) and 1 TB HDD as secondary storage. HDD has 4 partition on it.

[image: Partitions on Gparted]

1 partition (Data_W) is showing 232.85 GB in it .

But file manger on Kubuntu (Dolphin & Thunar File manager) is showing this partition's size only 3 GB. So I can't use my 229 GB storage. Other partitions are okay.

[image: Data_W partition showing only 3 GB]

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: I moved to kubuntu from windows a few months ago...

NTFS system was by default with system...

I want to dual boot Windows 11 again on Data_W partition...

I haven't edited disk format after moving to kubuntu (Because there was some files in it and other partitions were okay)...

Its my personal computer...

I will try with ntfsfix...

Thanks Nmath for your queries and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks mook765. I will definitely try this.

Comment: If I need then I can backup my data on HDD and format it. But I am planning to dual boot Windows 11 on a partition(Data_W) of HDD. Should I change DIsk format??

@Nmath

Comment: So thats mean I am having Kubuntu as main OS(on SSD) & Windows 11 as secondary OS (on HDD) @Nmath

Comment: A NTFS partition for shared data is appropriate if your device has dual boot config with Windows. But that doesn't explain why you have three of them. If Windows is installed, then use chkdisk on Windows on the problematic partition.

Comment: @Shezan It will not work for you, I overlooked that you have a NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I made sure that if any file was in the partition.

With Gparted running as superuse, I choose HDD.

I unmounted HDD first.

Then I formatted Data_W partition to (ntfs like other partition). This solved my problem.

And thus, I got to use full storage(232.85 GB) that was left out.

Comment: It will be automatically mounted later or restart your computer to mount HDD.

Comment: And I dual booted Windows 11 in Data_W too